# Not sure why "Element div is not closed" won't go away

Tags: html, element

Admittedly, I'm new to coding so I'm sure there may be many issues in my code. The errors that are showing up right now are all `Element div is not closed.` If someone can please help me resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you. My code is listed below:

```css
.instagramlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.linkedinlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- banner, navigation bar, logos which hyperlink to my socials -->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/shegonnacode/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-instagram-png-22629.png" alt="Instagram logo" class="instagramlogo"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/paula-m-175737200/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-linkedin-png-533561.png" alt="Linkedin logo" class="linkedinlogo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="lists.html">Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--About section begins-->
    <section class="welcome">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Welcome to Paula's Portfolio</h1>
        <p>Thank you for visiting my portfolio. This is a visual depiction of my internal creativity<br>and I hope you enjoy your experience. The navigation bar on the upper right corner
          <br>will direct you to your desired location. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="statement">
        <p> Paula Munoz, aspiring software developer and first year student currently enrolled in George Brown <br> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp College's Computer Programming
          and Analysis program.</p>
      </div>
      <!--validation script-->
      <script src=https://my.gblearn.com/js/loadscript.js></script>
</body>
```

As I stated, I am a noob with coding as I have tried to mess around with the arrangement of my divs and added+ and removed but my attempts have failed miserably. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Add a closing div, `</div>` to close `<div class="banner">`...this is your solution and it does not really need an answer, if my solution works for you please let me know and maybe delete this question...all elements like `div`, `p`, `li`, `h1`, etc... need closing tags to work. This is standard HTML syntax.

Comment: Try going to https://validator.w3.org/ and then choose "Validate by Direct Input" and past your HTML into it. I just did that for your HTML and I got 26 errors. The 26th error said there was no closing, </div>, tag. Actually some of the 26 were not really errors and some I couldn't understand...

Comment: I think most of the 26 errors were that you used &nbsp without the semicolon at the end. It should be &nbsp; as corrected in the answer to the question from Michael M

Answer (score 2):

The [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) (a great site to check for errors in HTML) shows three problems with your code:

- The `<div class="banner">` element is unclosed. This means that you never closed it with a corresponding `</div>` tag. All HTML tags must have an ending tag. Sometimes you might mess up and forget one by accident, so it is good to use the W3C Validator to detect these errors and show you where you messed up.
- The `<section class="welcome">` element is unclosed. Like the first error, you're missing a closing `</section>` tag.
- You used `&nbsp`, but you should have used `&nbsp;`. HTML escape codes are always in the format of `&something;`, starting with an ampersand and ending with a semicolon.

I've fixed these errors in the code below:

```css
.instagramlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.linkedinlogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- banner, navigation bar, logos which hyperlink to my socials -->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/shegonnacode/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-instagram-png-22629.png" alt="Instagram logo" class="instagramlogo"></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/paula-m-175737200/"><img src="images/pngfind.com-linkedin-png-533561.png" alt="Linkedin logo" class="linkedinlogo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="lists.html">Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--About section begins-->
  <section class="welcome">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Welcome to Paula's Portfolio</h1>
      <p>Thank you for visiting my portfolio. This is a visual depiction of my internal creativity<br>and I hope you enjoy your experience. The navigation bar on the upper right corner
        <br>will direct you to your desired location. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="statement">
      <p> Paula Munoz, aspiring software developer and first year student currently enrolled in George Brown <br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; College's
        Computer Programming and Analysis program.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--validation script-->
  <script src=https://my.gblearn.com/js/loadscript.js></script>
</body>
```

Comment: M I have just been looking at https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html. It seems that this might be better than the one without /nu in the path. Also there is a review at https://rocketvalidator.com/blog/w3c-validator-is-dead-long-live-validator-nu. For some reason I have not found anything in Visual Studio Code to help find errors in HTML although I have not tried very hard yet.